# CLI not working

Tags: php

I have installed Wamp on my PC (Windows 7), but whenever I want to start the server, it says that the CLI is not working. I also have Windows IIS server too, which I've installed from the Web Platform Installer but would that affect it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you have to make sure that IIS is not running, which will probably be the case after installing it. Search for your Web Services and disable or better deinstall IIS, since on Windows you never know if a later installation or program reconfiguration will without notice reenable your IIS service.